# How can I find is there is child having in tree component or not in PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to find whether the tree in primeface have child or not . When I select node in tree I need to find its having child or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check number of child with method getChildCount.
The `getChildCount()` will return 0 whenever selected node do not contains any children nodes.

```
public void onNodeSelect(NodeSelectEvent event) {
    TreeNode node = event.getTreeNode();
    System.out.println("node.getChildCount(): " + node.getChildCount());
}
```

Comment: thanks wittakam but there is one problem that it should not be parent (because if the parent with no child also consider as child ), do you have any solution  for that.

Comment: @koku you can check if(node != null && node.getChildCount()) for determine root is not have any childs.

Comment: Can you confirm what is node value??

Comment: @koku if(node != null && node.getChildCount() == 0), you can use  node.getData() for get node value.